# How to make tiles transparent?

Tags: settings, 8.1, tiles, personalization

I am using a Nokia Lumia 1020 with Windows Phone 8.1.

Some of the apps' tiles are automatically transparent and some (like Poki) offer an option to enable this. But there are many apps don't offer transparent tiles.

Is there any way to make any app's tile transparent so that the background shows through?

Comment: I take pains to inform each and every developer of the apps and request them to create transparent tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an app like [Transparency Tiles](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=f4125e62-a88b-4f7d-b8f6-3cd60069f105), it can make almost all your tiles transparent (with some exceptions), and works with both Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1.

Comment: yes got it just. :)