# Transparent tiles for core apps

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535, tiles

I want to use transparent tiles for Office, OneDrive, OneNote and OfficeLens. Is this possible? I had tried using **[Transparent Tile Maker App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/transparent-tiles-maker/9wzdncrfhzrz)** but it doesn't work for above mentioned apps. I am using WP8.1 on Lumia 535 DS (RM-1090) if this is relevant. I have also tried [Transparency Tiles](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/transparency-tiles/9wzdncrfj237) when I saw [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/how-to-make-tiles-transparent) question but this app also doesn't support such apps. (See the screenshot).

[image]

I have also tried [Tilesparency](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/tilesparency/9wzdncrfj2jb) app and it allows me to create transparent tiles for Office and OneNote.

But they are buggy as when I open Office app screen stucks at this screen.

[image]

And tapping on OneNote tile produces this error.

[image]

I have now updated on W10M so a solution purely W10M is also appreciated. My phone is 535 DS running W10M (14393.693) if relevant. if relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Windows Phone 8.1. A app developer ***Lazy Ideas*** says it as follows,

> But Office, OneNote and several others Apps *CAN'T* be opened this way
>   because of how Microsoft makes it work.

in his app description which can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/transparent-color-tiles/9wzdncrdj1cf#).

---

This is possible via 3rd party apps in **Windows 10 Mobile**. You can use an app such as [See Through tiles](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/see-through-tiles/9nblggh4pttp). It supports built apps such as Skype, Office, MSN Apps, etc...

Comment: But @Kolappan I had added transparent tiles as I mentioned in my edits. But do you mean that Microsoft don't allow such tiles to work properly? As in my case?

Comment: @User5 I saw the edits. This means that an option to open some built-in apps via other 3rd party applications was not implemented in Windows Phone 8.1. It is only present in Windows 10 Mobile. For a clear example, you can open a store page directly from AppRaisin or any app for WIndows 10 Mobile. But in WP 8.1 it was opened via Internet Explorer. I'm sorry. But WP8.1 is misssing those features.

Comment: SeeThrough tiles says that it cannot manage all the apps. I'll never have a fully transparent screen :(

Comment: @User5 That is unfortunate. SeeThroughTiles is the best app I could find that supports built-in apps such as Skype, Word, etc... What apps were not supported?

Comment: It does provide transparency for most of the apps but nothing is live! Just stationary, dumb but transparent tiles